# Unreliable connection for MySQL Connector C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm using the following code to access data from a MySQL database on a virtual machine that has a unique ip on the LAN :

```
conn = new MySqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
conn.OpenAsync();
// Data access here
conn.Close();
MySqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
```

The initial connection seems to be wonky, timing out sometimes. If I attempt to connect again after timing out it seems to connect immediately thou. Any ideas on how to remedy this?

Comment: Try `await conn.OpenAsync();`, and marking your method as async. (Or use `Open()` if you don't need to connect asynchronously.)

Comment: I've tried Open() both OpenAsync() with await and still no  luck